# Python Package addict force error if not existing

Tags: python

The package [`addict`](https://github.com/mewwts/addict) allows you to use dicts through attribute setting:

Example from the website:

```
from addict import Dict
body = Dict()
body.query.filtered.query.match.description = 'addictive'
body.query.filtered.filter.term.created_by = 'Mats'
```

Now when when I use for example `a = body.B` and I haven't included `B` yet it does not throw an error, but just returns nothing. How can I make it throw an error when the attribute was net yet set?

Comment: Unless you subclass it and change [`__missing__`](https://github.com/mewwts/addict/blob/master/addict/addict.py#L64-L65), which auto-generates a new `Dict` for any missing key, no. You can't have it both ways; if `body.query.filtered.query.match.description = 'addictive'` doesn't throw an error, `body.B` can't throw an error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is working as intended.

Comment: Also note that it doesn't return *nothing*, it returns an empty `Dict`, the one generated by the `__missing__` method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hm ... but can i somehow detect if it is used in an reading or writing expression, so i want to detect: a = body.B -> throw error, but body.B = "hello" -> no error

Comment: Again, only if you also want `body.whatever.something`, which also uses `__getattr__`, to fail too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes this is ok, i only need single nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addict.Dict` implements the [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) method to generate a value for any missing key(/attribute); the [current implementation](https://github.com/mewwts/addict/blob/62aec341d12ebbe313a67ce63838202ba9d9e742/addict/addict.py#L64-L65) generates a new `Dict` instance. If you don't want this behaviour, you'll have to override it:

```
class MyDict(Dict):

    def __missing__(self, name):
        raise KeyError(name)
```

Note that this will throw a `KeyError` for attribute access, which may be confusing; you could also override `__getattr__` if you want to throw an `AttributeError` instead. In use:

```
>>> body = MyDict()
>>> body.B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "path/to/addict.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    return self.__getitem__(item)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __missing__
KeyError: 'B'
>>> body.B = "hello"
>>> body.B
'hello'
```

Note also that this will break the other examples you showed as well, as e.g. `foo.bar.baz = qux` calls `__getattr__` on `foo` before calling `__setattr__` on `foo.bar` (if successful):

```
>>> body.query.filtered.query.match.description = 'addictive'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "path/to/addict.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    return self.__getitem__(item)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __missing__
KeyError: 'query'
```